# Xcode 9 iOS 11 BoringSSL session handshake failure error

Tags: ios, iphone, sslhandshakeexception, boringssl

I tried to rebuild existing app and it worked, but when I run the application, this runtime error comes out and cannot open web pages.

This app just connect to the web server and shows existing pages.

```
2018-08-14 16:34:15.478752+0900 mobileweb[331:16929] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.
2018-08-14 16:34:15.555930+0900 mobileweb[331:16929] [-[MainWebVC goURL:](246)] webView goURL : https://m.test.com/m.Index.do
2018-08-14 16:34:15.876538+0900 mobileweb[331:16929] [-[MainWebVC webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](314)] absoluteString : https://m.test.com/m.Index.do
2018-08-14 16:34:15.908827+0900 mobileweb[331:16976] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2866 [boringssl_session_handshake_continue] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library
2018-08-14 16:34:15.908887+0900 mobileweb[331:16976] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_handshake_error_print: line 2805 boringssl ctx 0x10150c5b0: 4414508304:error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.50.14/ssl/tls_record.c:547:SSL alert number 40
2018-08-14 16:34:15.908956+0900 mobileweb[331:16976] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_handshake_error_print: line 2805 boringssl ctx 0x10150c5b0: 4414508304:error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.50.14/ssl/handshake_client.c:946:
2018-08-14 16:34:15.908970+0900 mobileweb[331:16976] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_os_status: line 4268 SSL_AD_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
2018-08-14 16:34:15.913280+0900 mobileweb[331:16976] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c0172fc0]: 3:-9824 Err(-9824)
2018-08-14 16:34:15.913408+0900 mobileweb[331:16976] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
2018-08-14 16:34:15.913431+0900 mobileweb[331:16976] Task <9AE4442D-FF74-43BD-A02A-3F5E0D054C7B>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9824])
2018-08-14 16:34:15.914470+0900 mobileweb[331:16980] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200
2018-08-14 16:34:51.816506+0900 mobileweb[331:16929] [-[MainWebVC goURL:](246)] webView goURL : https://m.test.com/m.dayList.do
2018-08-14 16:34:51.850486+0900 mobileweb[331:16929] [-[MainWebVC webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](314)] absoluteString : https://m.test.com/m.dayList.do
2018-08-14 16:34:51.876909+0900 mobileweb[331:17143] TIC TCP Conn Failed [2:0x1c0173080]: 3:-9824 Err(-9824)
2018-08-14 16:34:51.877090+0900 mobileweb[331:17143] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
2018-08-14 16:34:51.877126+0900 mobileweb[331:17143] Task <4D8F7614-75D8-404E-98E3-56DDB6656DDC>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9824])
2018-08-14 16:34:51.878534+0900 mobileweb[331:17147] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200
2018-08-14 16:35:01.348073+0900 mobileweb[331:16929] [-[MainWebVC goURL:](246)] webView goURL : https://m.test.com/m.rateList.do
2018-08-14 16:35:01.379802+0900 mobileweb[331:16929] [-[MainWebVC webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](314)] absoluteString : https://m.test.com/m.rateList.do
2018-08-14 16:35:01.406302+0900 mobileweb[331:16979] TIC TCP Conn Failed [3:0x1c4171100]: 3:-9824 Err(-9824)
2018-08-14 16:35:01.406485+0900 mobileweb[331:16979] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
2018-08-14 16:35:01.406566+0900 mobileweb[331:16979] Task <90CFF81E-EFDA-4355-9CF5-F5ACC1C6EFE0>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9824])
2018-08-14 16:35:01.407895+0900 mobileweb[331:17191] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1200
```

For the record, m.test.com is tentative address and works for android app and other platform, and I think this repetitive TCP connection failure is something to do with first handshake failure, but I cannot get the reason of handshake failure..

Does anyone knows this symptom and how to fix it?